# AngularJS UI Router $state reload child state only

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am using UI router for tabs of a main menu as well as for links within one of the states (users).  The users state has a list of users and when a user is clicked, I want to reload the child state only, but it is reloading both the child state and the parent state (users).

Here's my code:

```
    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
            controller: 'HomeController as homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('users', {
            parent: 'home',
            url: '/users',
            templateUrl: '/User/Index',
            controller: 'UserController as userCtrl',
        })
        .state('users.createUser', {
            templateUrl: '/User/CreateUser',
            controller: 'CreateUserController as cuCtrl'
        })
        .state('users.editUser', {
            templateUrl: '/User/EditUser',
            controller: 'EditUserController as euCtrl',
            resolve: {
                userInfo: function (contextInfo, userData) {
                    return userData.get(contextInfo.getUserKey());
                }
            }
        })
        .state('users.addWebItemsForUser', {
            templateUrl: '/User/AddWebItemsForUser',
            controller: 'UserWebItemsController as uwiCtrl'
        })
        .state('users.addReportsForUser', {
            templateUrl: '/User/AddReportsForUser',
            controller: 'UserReportsController as urCtrl'
        })
        .state('users.userGroups', {
            templateUrl: '/User/UserGroups',
            controller: 'UserGroupController as userGroupCtrl'
        })
        //.state('users.logInWebApp', {
        //    template: '<h3>Logging into web app</h3>',
        //    resolve: {
        //        user: function() {
        //            return {
        //                //companyId: contextInfo.getCustomerKey()
        //                //userId:
        //                //password:
        //            }
        //        }
        //    },
        //    controller: function() {
        //        // need company code, username and password of user then need to open window with webapp url (will that work?) - do we still want to add this functionality?
        //    }
        //})
        .state('links', {
            url: '/links',
            templateUrl: '/Link/Index',
            controller: 'LinkController as linkCtrl'
        })
        .state('onlrpts', {
            url: '/onlineReports',
            templateUrl: '/OnlineReport/Index',
            controller: 'OnlineReportController as onlRptCtrl'
        })
        .state('reports', {
            url: '/customerReports',
            templateUrl: '/CustomerReport/Index',
            controller: 'CustomerReportController as custRptCtrl'
        });
})
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $stateParams) {
        $delegate.forceReload = function() {
            return $delegate.go($delegate.$current.name, $stateParams, {
                reload: true,
                inherit: false,
                notify: true
            });
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

This is the function in my parent controller (UserController) that is called when a user is clicked:

```
            this.userTreeClick = function(e) {
        contextInfo.setUserKey(e.Key);
        contextInfo.setUserName(e.Value);
        userCtrl.userKey = e.Key;
        $state.forceReload();
    };
```

So say I was in the users.userGroups state, when I click on another user, I want only the users.userGroups state to be reloaded.  Is this possible?  I have looked for an answer via Google and here at StackOverflow, but I haven't found anything that is exactly like what I am trying to do.  When I break to check the $state.$current.name - the name is correct - users.userGroups, but it reloads everything instead of just the child state.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As documented in API Reference , we can use **`$state.reload`**:

> #### [$state.reload(state)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_reload)
>
> A method that force reloads the current state. All resolves are
>   re-resolved, controllers reinstantiated, and events re-fired.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `state` *(optional)*
>
>   - A state name or a state object, which is the root of the resolves to be re-resolved.

An example:

```
//will reload 'contact.detail' and 'contact.detail.item' states
$state.reload('contact.detail');
```

Similar we can achieve with a *`$state.go()`* and its `options` parameter:

> #### [$state.go(to, params, options)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go)
>
> ...
>
> - `options` (optional)
>
>   - `location` ...
>   - `inherit` ...
>   - `relative` ...
>   - `notify` ...
>   - `reload` (v0.2.5) - {boolean=false|string|object}, If true will force transition even if no state or params have changed. It will
>       reload the resolves and views of the current state and parent states.
>       **If reload is a string (or state object), the state object is fetched (by name, or object reference); and \ the transition reloads the
>       resolves and views for that matched state, and all its children
>       states.**

Example from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1612#issuecomment-77757224 by Chris T:

```
{ reload: true } // reloads all,
{ reload: 'foo.bar' } // reloads top.bar, and any children
{ reload: stateObj } // reloads state found in stateObj, and any children
```

An example

```
$state.go('contact', {...}, {reload: 'contact.detail'});
```

Comment: I thank you so much for your help.  I tried to incorporate what you've shown here and the other entry, but it is not working.  I am unable to see the plunker (I get plunk not found).  I should have mentioned that I am using this in conjunction with MVC.  The User/UserGroups go to a controller action which returns a partial view. '            .state('users.userGroups', {
                templateUrl: '/User/UserGroups/{userTrigger}',
                controller: 'UserGroupController as userGroupCtrl'
            })
'

Comment: Continued:  Here is the controller code : `        this.userTreeClick = function(e) {
            contextInfo.setUserKey(e.Key);
            contextInfo.setUserName(e.Value);
            userCtrl.userKey = e.Key;
            var params = angular.copy($state.params);
            params.userTrigger = params.userTrigger === null ? "" : null;
            $state.transitionTo($state.current, params, { reload: false, inherit: true, notify: true });
        };
Forgot to mention that now nothing is happening.  The change is not reloading the state.

Comment: If I use this method the child state is reloaded, but it is reloaded twice?

Comment: Have you compared your setting with my plunker? is it same? or is there any difference? Maybe you should raise a question with more details

Answer (score 28):

The current ui-router (0.2.14 and above) added support to reload child state.

Simply put `$state.go('your_state', params, {reload: 'child.state'});` will do the job.

See: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1612 and 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1809/files

Comment: Is there a way to do this with ui-sref?

Comment: @AlxVallejo you can use `ui-sref-opts` for example: `<a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-opts="{reload: 'home.child'}">Home</a>`

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten it to work. I used what Radim suggested, but I had to add the **url** element to the state.

```
.state('users.userGroups', {
    url: '/userGroups/{userTrigger}',
    templateUrl: '/User/UserGroups',
    controller: 'UserGroupController as userGroupCtrl'
})
```

and in my controller, when a user clickes on a link, I use the `$state.transitionTo`:

```
var params = angular.copy($state.params);
params.userTrigger = params.userTrigger === null ? "" : null;
$state.transitionTo($state.current, params, { reload: false, inherit: true, notify: true });
```

Just an FYI for any other newbies out there:

> after I added the **url** to the `.state`, I started having issues with my api calls.  It was prepending the urls to the api methods with the url in my `.state`. You just have to be sure to have a leading `/` in your api urls:

```
.factory('usersInGroup', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function(groupName) {
            return $http.get('/api/UserApi/GetInGroup/' + groupName);
        }
    }
```

I saw and learned some pretty interesting stuff trying to muddle through this...

Answer (score -1):

```
$state.transitionTo("State Here", {"uniqueRequestCacheBuster": null});
```

This will simply reload only that child state as you wanted. not the whole hierarchy of states.