# Ui-Router $state.go() does not refresh data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a Product List state and Product Edit/Add state in my Angular app.

Product List data gets loaded in the controller (I didn't think I need resolve to be defined in state config) which gets data from an ngResource:

```
function InventoryListCtrl (myResource) {
  var vm = this;

  myResource.query(function (data) {
    vm.products = data;
  });
}
```

On Edit Controller, after I edit a product I get back to list state like this:

```
vm.product.$update().$promise;
$state.go('productList');
```

It doesn't load list with new data always, it shows old data in first run generally, then after I do second update and manually get back to list state it starts to refresh after each update.

I've tried this, but didn't work either:

```
vm.product.$update().$promise;
$state.go('productList', {}, { reload: true });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think you're loading the new state before the update has completed - try moving the state transition to after the update completion:

```
vm.product.$update().then(function(){
  $state.go('productList', {}, { reload: true });
});
```

Comment: It was a mistake on my part to write $promise after ngResource method. Your answer is correct otherwise. Thanks

Comment: Not what OP was asking but it is something I wish I had learned sooner. If you want to only reload a child state you need to change "reload: true" to have the child state name instead of true as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316591/angularjs-ui-router-state-reload-child-state-only/31887658#31887658

Comment: `$state.reload()` now works as a shorthand to the full $state.go(etc...)

Answer (score 14):

i think this should work for current state refresh.

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams
```

Comment: This also worked for me, wrapped inside of an ng-click such as

 `ng-click="$state.go('dashboard', {}, {reload: true})"`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a list not refreshing after edit. Wrapping the $state.go in a $timeout function solved my problem.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $state.go('publishers.list', {}, { reload: true });
},200);
```